# HttpMethod.POST and HttpMethod.GET methods are not working in Facebook SDK for Unity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

```
FB.API("https://graph.facebook.com/"+FB.UserId+"?fields=id,first_name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,    LogCallback);
FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);
function LogCallback(response:String) {
Debug.Log(response);
}
```

I am not getting any response in any of these 2 API calls. I think the problem is because Facebook.HttpMethod.GET is not working or doesn't exist. Someone please help me out with this.
I am not able to get profile picture or update score for a user.

Comment: Hi Rohit. Can you explain more what you mean when you say Facebook.HttpMethod.GET doesn't exist? Can you put an example project somewhere I can take a look at it? (e.g. github)

Comment: @aaron Sorry May bad! HttpMethod are working. Somehow the response is not getting printed in DDMS log but if you parse the response and try to print individual values then it gives you the right values.

Comment: @aaron Though I got one confusing problem doing this
I got response as true from score API but the score is not getting published on my wall. 

FB.API("/"+USER_ID+"/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);
function LogCallback(response:String) {
Debug.Log(response);
}

I have already provided publish_actions permission so whenever I break my previous score it should publish it on my timeline like this
"Rohit got a new high score in Live Hungry Hamster. as told in the Scores API docs but it is not happening. And the score is definitely getting saved in score API.

Answer (score 2):

Rohit, is the score still not visible on your activity log (on your timeline, click Activity Log, then filter down to stories from your app)?

Comment: Hi Colin this time the story got published on activity log. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
FB.API("https://graph.facebook.com/"+FB.UserId+"?fields=id,first_name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,    LogCallback);
```

should be just

```
FB.API(FB.UserId+"?fields=id,first_name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `Facebook.HttpMethod.GET` with `Facebook.Unity.HttpMethod.GET` as per your assembly directive.
This worked fine for me!

```
FB.API(FB.UserId+"?fields=id,first_name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
```

Should  be

```
FB.API(FB.UserId+"?fields=id,first_name", Facebook.Unity.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
```